# Improve Fabric.js performance

Tags: jquery, performance-testing, fabricjs

Here is my test script. I want to add around thousand rectangles on image. but browser crash when I un-comment all function calls `AddRectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2)` .

http://jsfiddle.net/talkwaqar/efhg2/

Can any one help me make it show these all smoothly without any problem in the browser.

Can you please share any updated code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need this:

```
canvas.renderOnAddRemove = false;
```

to avoid canvas re-rendering on every add.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/efhg2/2/

Comment: maybe You know how to improve performance with 5k elements? I have problem when i want to select and drag element. It takes 2-3s before it selects.